# Passing data to parent - recipebook React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on the recipe book app and trying to implement the edit entry function. 
How it works is to input recipe name (e.g Pasta), followed by ingredients (e.g egg, flour, salt). The ingredients have to be input with commas and will be shown as a list.

- Pasta
- -Egg
- -Flour

i can see that it is somewhat working, because i can see the new entries in the input text (e.g initially was egg,flour,salt -> egg,flour,salt,water) when i tried to edit it again.

However, the extra ingredients (in the above example: water) is not showing up in the list. Do i have to figure a way to re-render the list?

**updates:**
I think i know where the error might be. There is some issue passing the data and setting the state.

```
<EditRecipe recipe={this.props.recipe} editRecipe={this.editRecipe.bind(this, this.props.recipe.id, recipe)}/>
```

App.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import uuid from 'uuid';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import RecipeList from './components/RecipeList/RecipeList';
import AddRecipe from './components/AddRecipe/AddRecipe';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      recipes:[]
    };
  }

  getRecipes(){
    this.setState({recipes:[
      {
        id: uuid.v4(),
        food: "pumpkin pie",
        ingredients: ["pumpkin puree", "sweetened condensed milk", "eggs", "pumpkin pie spice", "pie crust"]
      },
      {
        id: uuid.v4(),
        food: "spaghetti",
        ingredients: ["noodles", "tomato sauce", "meatballs"]
      },
      {
        id: uuid.v4(),
        food: "onion pie",
        ingredients: ["onion", "pie crust"]
      },

    ]});
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.getRecipes();
  }

  handleAddRecipe(recipe){
    let recipes = this.state.recipes;
    recipes.push(recipe);
    this.setState({recipes: recipes});
  }

  handleDeleteRecipe(id){
    let recipes = this.state.recipes;
    let index = recipes.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
    recipes.splice(index,1);
    this.setState({recipes: recipes});
  }

  handleEditRecipe(id, recipe){
    let recipes = this.state.recipes;
    let index = recipes.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
    recipes.splice(index,1,recipe);
    this.setState({recipes: recipes});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <RecipeList  recipes={this.state.recipes} onDelete={this.handleDeleteRecipe.bind(this)} onEdit={this.handleEditRecipe.bind(this)}/>
        <AddRecipe addRecipe={this.handleAddRecipe.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

RecipeList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Collapsible from 'react-collapsible';
import RecipeItem from '../RecipeItem/RecipeItem'
import './RecipeList.css';

class RecipeList extends Component{

deleteRecipe(id){
  this.props.onDelete(id);
}

editRecipe(id, recipe){
  this.props.onEdit(id, recipe);
}

  render(){

    let recipeItem;

    if(this.props.recipes){
      recipeItem=this.props.recipes.map(recipe => {
        return(
          <RecipeItem onEdit={this.editRecipe.bind(this)} onDelete={this.deleteRecipe.bind(this)} key={recipe.id} recipe={recipe} />
        )
      });
    }

    return(
      <div className="recipeList box">
      {recipeItem}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default RecipeList;
```

RecipeItem.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Collapsible from 'react-collapsible';
import EditRecipe from '../EditRecipe/EditRecipe';

class RecipeItem extends Component{

  deleteRecipe(id){
    this.props.onDelete(id);
  }

  editRecipe(id, recipe){
    this.props.onEdit(id, recipe);
  }

  render(){

    let recipe=this.props.recipe
    let foodName=recipe.food;
    let ingredientItem;

    if(recipe.ingredients){
      ingredientItem=recipe.ingredients.map(ingredient=>{
        return(
          <a className="panel-block">
            {ingredient}
          </a>
        )
      })
    }
    return(
      <ul>
        <li className="Recipe">
        <Collapsible trigger={foodName} transitionTime="200" easing="ease-in-out">
        <nav className="panel">
          <p className="panel-heading">
            Ingredients
          </p>
          {ingredientItem}
          <div className="panel-block">
            <button className="button is-warning is-outlined" onClick={this.deleteRecipe.bind(this, this.props.recipe.id)}>
              Delete
            </button>
            <EditRecipe recipe={this.props.recipe} editRecipe={this.editRecipe.bind(this, this.props.recipe.id, recipe)}/>
          </div>
          </nav>
        </Collapsible>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default RecipeItem;
```

EditRecipe.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RecipeForm from '../RecipeForm/RecipeForm';
// import './EditRecipe.css';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import uuid from 'uuid';
// import Modal from 'boron/DropModal';
// import './RecipeList.css';

class RecipeEdit extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      revisedRecipe:{
        id: this.props.recipe.id,
        food: this.props.recipe.food,
        ingredients: this.props.recipe.ingredients
      },
      modalIsOpen: false,
      speed: 100
    };
    this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
  }

  openModal(){
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: true});
  }

  closeModal(){
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
  }

  handleSubmit(e){

    const revised = this.state.revisedRecipe;

    this.props.editRecipe(revised);

    e.preventDefault();
  }


  handleNameChange(e){
    this.setState({revisedRecipe:{
      food: e.target.value
    }
  });
  }

  handleIndChange(e){
    this.setState({revisedRecipe:{
      ingredients: e.target.value
    }
  });
  }



  render(){
    const speed = this.state.speed;
    let recipe=this.props.recipe;
    let foodName=this.state.revisedRecipe.food;
    let ingredients=recipe.ingredients;

    return(
      <div>
        <button className="button is-primary" onClick={this.openModal}>Edit Recipe</button>
        <Modal
          isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
          onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal}
          onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
          closeTimeoutMS={speed}
          contentLabel="Example Modal"
        >
        <div className="field">
          <h2 className="title is-2">Edit Recipe</h2>
          <form>
            <label className="label">Recipe</label>
            <div className="control">
              <input className="input" type="text" placeholder="Recipe Name" ref="recipeName" value={this.state.revisedRecipe.food} onChange={this.handleNameChange.bind(this)}/>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
            <label className="label">Ingredients</label>
            <div className="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
              <input className="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter ingredients. (if more than 1 ingredient, separate them with commas)" ref="ingredients" value={this.state.revisedRecipe.ingredients} onChange={this.handleIndChange.bind(this)}/>
              <span className="icon is-small is-left">
                <i className="fa fa-flask"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className="field is-grouped">
              <div className="control">
                <button className="button is-primary" onClick={this.closeModal}>Edit Recipe</button>
              </div>
              <div className="control">
                <button className="button" onClick={this.closeModal}>Cancel</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RecipeEdit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're actually getting an error when trying to re-render after updating a list. The ingredients property in the recipes are an array (as shown in `getRecipes()`) but you're setting the new state of ingredients (in EditRecipe) as a string: `"egg,flour,salt,water"` and then trying to render the ingredients as an array: `ingredients.map()`.

When you render an input field with an array `<input value={["egg", "flour"]} />` it does show the values separated by comma, but the `event.target.value` in `onChange` is actually a string.

In EditRecipe's, `handleIndChange` could be fixed with:

```
this.setState({revisedRecipe: {ingredients: e.target.value.split(',')}});
```

This does have another problem, though in that you are overriding the `revisedRecipe` completely. So all of the `setState` calls should be something like:

```
const recipe = this.state.revisedRecipe;
recipe.ingredients = e.target.value.split(',');
this.setState({revisedRecipe: recipe);
```

Comment: i tried changing the handleIndChange. still doesn't work.